# Background job access secured APIs with Azure AD

Tags: asp.net-web-api, oauth, oauth-2.0, azure-active-directory

My web api use Azure AD to authenticate and authorized. I also have a background job that will call to the secured api in a period of time.

The problem is in order to call the api, the background job must be authenticated by log-in and get access token. But the background job is running silently and it can not prompt a window to type user credential.

Is there any approach to call the secured API in the backgroud job?

My work around are i store an encrypted username/password of a super user. When my background job run, it will acquire the token with the username/password. After that attach it to the header and call the api.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the OAuth 2.0 client credentials grant to access web-hosted resources by using the identity of an application.

With client credential flow , application requests an access token by using its application identity and presenting its Application ID, credential (password or certificate), and application ID URI to Azure AD. After successful authentication, the daemon receives an access token from Azure AD, which is then used to call the web API.

Please click here for more details about [Daemon or Server Application to Web API scenario](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/active-directory-authentication-scenarios#daemon-or-server-application-to-web-api) .

And [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/active-directory-code-samples#server-or-daemon-application-to-web-api) is code samples show how to build a daemon or server application that gets resources from a web API by using Azure AD Authentication Library (ADAL) and OAuth 2.0 in Azure AD.